# In a rails, where does one place a bundled React JS file that will be referenced by a single view?

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-5

I need to place a single `my_custom_app.js` file (a bundled-with-webpack React app) somewhere inside the default project structure of a Rails app.

Then I plan to reference said file **only from a single view** (
 `app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb`).

I *think* that I don't need this file to be part of the asset pipeline. I would like Rails to version it's filename by adding that hash but I definitely **don't** want it concatenated with the rest of the JS of the site.

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited to change my rails version to 5 (from the erroneous 4 I had initially)

Comment: did you use react with `webpacker` gem? if yes you can just call `<%= javascript_pack_tag 'directory_to_your_file' %>`

Comment: @rudydydy: Ah actually no! I do _not_ want to change the existing asset pipeline or mess with it in any way. I'm simply after including a single .js file (which happens to be a fully fledged React app) from one of the RoR views.